# Disable image cdn stuck

Tags: magento-1, image, cdn

I am having an issue with my Magento site and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I recently migrated my Magento  (1.4.1.1) site from Rackspace to a private server. The site was configured to load image cdn from Rackspace. Since migrating, the images do not load on any page, and all the menu's are missing, most of the website is displaying black. When the site is loading i can see that it is still trying to load the images from Rackspace and the images are still linked to it as well. How can i disable this and load the images from my server. All images are currently on my server as the whole directory was shifted over.

Comment: Did you clear the cache post migration? Do you have CDN URL configured under site URL configuration in Magento admin. Make sure to update the URL if it's there. Clear cache, reindex to make the things working. Last and not the list did you migrated the DNS, hope that is not causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, i cleared the cache, no i have the default url links for images, ect on the domain name and server. I have already reindex all pages and cleared cache and flush catalogue image cache and flush css cache. Yes i have migrated the dns the site has been on my server for over a month with this issue. Any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Not sure if you have permission issue. Try deleting var/cache folder manually. Hope that will resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried to manually delete the var/cache folder but still have the same issue?

Comment: There is something missing for sure. Either on your product page you using hardcoded image URL instead of Magento functionality or the URL is incorrectly configured in site configuration. You would have to check at site and site view level to confirm the same. Do you have a DNS entry pointing to rackspace?